# How to execute embedded html tags into angular value binding like this : {{variable}}?

Tags: html, angular, string, dynamic, interpolation

I have one variable in which string is passed by user.

```
let string = "we found {value} locations in {city} city. please search another city."
```

I want to show it to the user and I need to `replace` it with some values. I am showing this msg like this :

```
<p>{{string}}</p>
```

Now before this msg show to the user, I have to replace this values using str.replACE function like this :

```
this.string = this.string.replace("{value}", this.count)
this.string = this.string.replace("{city}", this.city)
```

and then show this string into html.. that is works fine. but I want to bold that replaced value in html..

I have tried to append like this :

```
this.string = this.string.replace("{value}", '<b>' + this.count + '</b>')
this.string = this.string.replace("{city}", '<b>' + this.city + '</b>')
```

But this will print `<b>` also in UI.
I don't know how to interpolate this string;

I don't want to use InnerHTML method for replace string into selector using VanillaJS.

If anyone have a deep knowledge about `interpolation in dynamic string with styling` then please help me.

**Note:**  In short , {{variable}} should execute `"HTML"` also in angular.

Comment: I have founded this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding for execute html. but any other way to do this. then please answer here. it will be appreciated

Comment: @yazan, This is alternative Solution which actually alter whole inner html in that tag.
I need advance interpolation in angular that can enable to modify only that string within html template of that component.

Comment: You could create a custom pipe for that case

Comment: Using pipe will modify your string, replace any and style  the text you are providing, usage will be like this <p [innerHTML] = "string | stylingPipe"></p> and modify edit your string in the pipe, See https://stackblitz.com/edit/linkify-pipe?file=app%2Flinkify.pipe.ts

Answer (score 1):

Use innerHTML like this:

```
<p [innerHTML]="string"></p>
```

Comment: Thank You buddy for answer it, but, I already tried this and works successfully...
and I needs another way to show it using advance interpolation in angular

Comment: Welcome, tho I am not sure what you mean by "advance interpolation", I can maybe help you if you explain your needs a bit more.

Comment: Simple interpolation is like this : "this is `${variable}` value"
I can't write any html inside that variable because it prints in UI. I needs to execute that html stored in variable into this html.
In short I want : "this is `${<b>10</b>}` value"
10 should looks bold in html